# Writing a code that can count the minimum option

Tags: c

I wrote a code that counts the maximum combinations possible to make a number using , 200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){

  int num, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, 
     counter = 0;
  float temp = 0;
  printf("What is the amount that you like to check? (or press '0' to exit)\n");
  scanf_s("%d", &num);


  for (a = 0; a < 3; a++)  \\ using loops to count the combinations just like in a safe 
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            for (d = 0; d < 15; d++)
                for (e = 0; e < 50; e++)
                {
                    if (num < a * 200 + b * 100 + c * 50 + d * 20 + e * 10)
                        break;
                    for (f = 0; f < 100; f++)
                    {
                        if (num < a * 200 + b * 100 + c * 50 + d * 20 + e * 10 + f * 5)
                            break;
                        for (g = 0; g < 250; g++)
                        {
                            if (num < a * 200 + b * 100 + c * 50 + d * 20 + e * 10 + f * 5 + g * 2)
                                break;
                            for (h = 0; h < 500; h++)
                            {
                                if (num == h);
                                temp = h;

                                if (num == a * 200 + b * 100 + c * 50 + d * 20 + e * 10 + f * 5 + g * 2 + h)
                                {
                                    counter++;  \\ Counting the combinations possible.
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
   printf("The number of possibilities is: %d.\n", counter);
   temp = num*0.004;  \\ used to count the maximum weight 
   printf("the maximum weight is %.4f\n", temp);
}
```

For example: 5 can be made from `5,221,2111,11111`.

Now my next task is to count the minimum and maximum weight from that combination, the weight goes like this : `"200,100,50"`- all weights 1 gr, 
but,

```
"10" weighs 7 gr, 
"5" weighs 8.2 gr ,
"2" weighs 5.7 and
 "1" weighs 4 gr
```

now the problem is that I thought the minimum weight would be 
- for example

```
"233" will be 200 + 20 + 10 + 2 + 1 which in total is 18.7
```

but in fact 
the minimum weight is

```
100 + 50 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 2 + 1
 which is 15.7
```

so I have no idea how to count that, does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* A homework help site. Try [r/homeworkhelp](http://reddit.com/r/homeworkhelp)

Comment: `void main()` should really be `int main(void)` in order to be standard compatible